Is there any LinkedIn API available for updating user profile image
I need LinkedIn API for updating profile image. It's needed to serve some of use-cases of application that I'm working on
I tried proxycurl. this particular API, LinkedIn API docs and others as well. it is not available.

This question is similar to: Updating profiles with the LinkedIn REST API. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
